# Why do I have not necessary pagination buttons with jQuery DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, pagination

I have a problem on a DataTables using pagination with server-side request.

It looks like the number of pagination buttons is not related to my results.
I always have buttons for pages 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, no matter how many results I have.

My DataTables definition:

```
$('#tableau_reponses').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url: '/my_api/get_reponses_ajax',
            type: 'post',
            data: formData
        },
        "paging": true,
        "searching": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ordering": false,
        "info": false,
        "pagingType": "numbers",
        "pageLength": 20,
        "lengthMenu": [10, 20, 50, 100],
        'order': [[1, 'asc']],
        'columnDefs': [
            {
                'targets': 0,
                'orderable': false,
                'className': 'dt-body-center',
                'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
                    return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
                }
            },
            {
                'targets': 1,
                'render': function (data) {
                    return '<td class="response_state_folder"></td>';
                }
            }
        ],
    });
```

On my test environment, I know I have 29 results. My pageLength is set to 20.
So by default, on page 1, I have 20 results. When I select page 2, I have 9 results. So far so good.
But when I select page 3, 4 or 5 (and I shouldn't be able to) I have 0 results.

Why do I have "3, 4, 5" buttons when, with 29 results, I should have only 2 pages?
Of course if I have 142 results I need 8 pages...

I think I'm missing something pretty obvious here...

Thanks for your help!

===== EDIT =====

Following [@Ashu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65671159/7856997), I've managed to get "recordsFiltered" and "recordsTotal" in my response (respectively "20" and "29" in my example). But now, I have only one button (for page 1) where I'm expecting two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server response must return how many `rows` are there in the filtered response from the database, and how many rows are there in total so as the database so it can set the pagination values right.

Example response :

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 57, // these both are important and must be updated in every response 
    "recordsFiltered": 20, // 
    "data": [
        [
            "Angelica",
            "Ramos",
            "System Architect",
            "London",
            "9th Oct 09",
            "$2,875"
        ],
    ]
}
```

If you need help on server-side code, You can edit or ask a new question.

More in the documentation [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot, the values I get in recordsTotal and recordsFiltered (which were missing in my previous attempts) are correct, but now I have the opposite problem, not enough buttons (see my edit).

Comment: Make sure you've right values coming through, if there are filters added in the query, make sure the total count is also filtered, If you still have problems, edit or ask a new question with more details

Comment: Ok, it works, my bad, I had a little lack of understanding about the difference between "recordsFiltered" and "recordsTotal": in my case they should by equal. Thanks again for your help!